# How can I easily confirm domain ownership via email using only self-hosted solutions?

Tags: email

I'm trying to configure many self-hosted solutions and every one of them require SMTP email configuration info (for notifications)

I own multiple subdomains for my main domain, and also I use Mandrill service to send emails.

Mandrill require DKIM, SPF and email verification (it sends email and I press link to verify)

I can verify DKIM and SPF for those domains, but I don't know how to verify multiple subdomain emails (e.g.: info@git.mydomain.com, info@chat.mydomain.com) for those services without hustle.

Often I'm using my hosting provider paid feature - create mail box for domain/subdomain, but with many self-hosted solutions this feature comes as somewhat expensive.

Thanks!

Comment: A lot of places seem to provide email forwarding for free (just forward all of your domains to one mailbox), or places that sell mailboxes give aliases for free (set up aliases for all your domains, then set the MX records on those domains to point to that provider). Those are the easy options, but they don't really seem to have anything to do with [unix.se]. The other option is to run your own mail server; receiving email is easy (getting others to accept your emails is the hard part). That makes sense on [unix.se], but "how do I set up a mail server"? is a bit beyond a single question.

Comment: @derobert thank you! I managed to use G-Suite for free with account aliases.